# How to get ResourceId from AAD application

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I want to fetch the Access Token from AAD application using below snippet.

```
var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { ResourceId + "/.default" }) { }
);
```

I have created AAD application on Azure portal, How to get ResourceId from the AAD application?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: Resource ID depends on the Azure resource you want to authenticate the Azure AD Application (Microsoft Graph, Web Api etc).

For **sample**, I passed `https://graph.microsoft.com` as **`resourceId`** to authenticate Microsoft Graph API.

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;

// Define the resource ID for the Azure AD application you want to access.
string resourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
    new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { resourceId + "/.default" })
);

Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
```

[image]

I agree with @*juunas*, if you want to authenticate the web Api you can pass `resourceId` as the ClientID or the API URL of the Azure AD Application like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: To fetch the access token for web Api, you must add Microsoft Azure CLI with client ID
> `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46` as the Authorized client application.

*Go to the Azure AD App -> Expose an API -> Add client application with `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46` and check the scope.*

[image]

And make sure to grant the API permissions:

[image]

```cs
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;


// Define the resource ID for the Azure AD application you want to access.
string resourceId = "api://ClientID";

var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

var accessToken = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(
    new TokenRequestContext(scopes: new string[] { resourceId + "/.default" })
);

Console.WriteLine(accessToken.Token);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's the Application ID URI in your screenshot.
You can technically use either the Application (client) ID or the Application ID URI. Both identify the application.